# Isaac Gym - Conflicting(?) Python and CUDA Requirements

Tags: python, pytorch, nvidia-isaac

I'm trying to start working with Nvidia's Isaac Gym software in a new Conda environment and am running into some issues.

Firstly, the software requires a Conda environment of Python 3.8.

Secondly, the software requires Pytorch be installed and functional with my GPU. I have a 3080 Ti, which means Pytorch needs to be installed with CUDA 11.3 (or, at least, newer than 10.2). As Isaac Gym's setup installs it with CUDA 10.2, I need to install Pytorch elsewhere.

Whenever I run the CUDA 11.3 Pytorch install in the Conda environment as described by the menu on https://pytorch.org/, it bumps the Python version in the Conda environment.

My workflow is described below:

**1. Create the Conda environment:**

```
conda create --name isaacEnv python=3.8
```

**2. Activate the Conda environment:**

```
conda activate isaacEnv
```

**3. Check Python version, which returns Python 3.8.13**

```
python --version
```

This returns `Python 3.8.13`

**4. Install the rest of the Nvidia Isaac Gym stuff.**

This step doesn't impact any later steps but is detailed in their installation documentation (downloadable from their website). It does not end up mattering because the script they use installs `torch` with Cuda 10.2, which--as stated--is incompatible with my 3080 Ti.

This step is also likely independent of the problem, as the next step causes issues regardless:

**5. Install Pytorch with CUDA 11.3**

As detailed on pytorch.org:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch
```

At this stage, even if I hit "no" to cancel the installation, when I run `python --version` again, it will show `Python 3.9.12`, which is the default version on this PC.

**tl;dr:** Is there a way to install Pytorch with CUDA 11.3 without upgrading from Python 3.8 in the Conda environment in the process?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same question today.

It seems like you just need to open another terminal, and the python version will revert to normal... Maybe it's something about CUDA.

Update: I have considered this question again. Now I tend to that this is a bug with conda updating. After I created the new env, I run an updating just as what conda advised me to do. And since then the python attaching to my terminal was always the one in base env.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).